# Can I update my kernel in 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, kernel, updates

I am using kernel version 2.6.35 in Ubuntu 10.10. Can I update my kernel to the latest version, which is **v3.2-rc3-oneiric** as seen on **http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/** ?

Comment: and the version of the kernel you have there is an oneric one, won't work on maverick. just update to 11.10 or leave it.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work @Alvar? i have used kernels not meant for the current releases and they work fine.

Comment: we discussed it in the chat and I think he didn't want to do it after that... general room earlier today, around 14-15..

Comment: @Alvar link to the transcript if you can.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see it's not available a deb package of the linux kernel image v3.2-rc3 at the moment, but when it will be available you should be able to upgrade provided that you first install:

[for a 32 bit system](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/module-init-tools/3.16-1ubuntu1/+build/2572761/+files/module-init-tools_3.16-1ubuntu1_i386.deb)

OR

[for 64 bit](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/73623441/module-init-tools_3.16-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb)

After that, just download and install the three files you need from the link you posted (the xxx_all.deb and both xxx_i386.deb or xxx._amd64.deb).
Finally don't forget to run sudo update-grub2 from a terminal.
Note that it's not guaranteed to work properly, since the package it's not intended for maverick (and of course this is a release candidate!)